# SQL Server provider on Mono - Multiple result sets are not supported

Tags: sql-server, mono

In our application, I have a method in DAL which executes an SQL query which should return 2 result sets. I use dapper to map the result sets to DTOs. Works fine on windows.

While running on Mono, the query fails to fetch the results (Dapper throws null ref exception).

Other SQL queries work fine on Mono. The application is able to read/write to SQL server just fine.

Are there any known issues with multiple result sets in Mono SQL server driver?
I wasn't able to find any documented outstanding issues.

Here's the method's code:

```
using (var connection = ConnectionFactory.OpenConnection())
{
    if (connection == null)
    {
        throw new System.ApplicationException("Could not open DB connection for DAL.");
    }

    Logger?.Trace("Got connection for DAL.");

    var sql = @"SELECT A.x, A.y FROM A;

                SELECT A.x, B.z, B.w
                FROM C INNER JOIN A ON C.x = A.x
                INNER JOIN B ON C.z = B.z";

    using (var multiRes = connection.QueryMultiple(sql))
    {
        if(multiRes == null)
        {
            throw new System.ApplicationException("No results returned from db.");
        }

        res.AddRange(multiRes.Read<aDTO>());

        var mapping = multiRes.Read<aDTO, bDTO, aDTO>((a, b) =>
        {
            ...
            return a;
        }, splitOn: "z").ToList();                        
    }       
}
```